# How to move files in a batch to different folders based on result of an upload with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I'm new to WinSCP. I'm trying to set an Errorlevel for the batch IM running. If the Errorlevel=  0 PRINT SUCCESS and transfers those files with Errorlevel 0 to folder call success.
if the error not equal to  0 moves the file with the error level to different folder call errors. Any suggestions.

HERE IS MY.bat

```
WinSCP.exe /console /script="c:\users\PDP\script.txt" /log="c:\users\PDP\lastrun.txt"
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 
echo Success
sendmail.exe -t < success_mail.txt
move OPTTXM* c:\users\PDP\sent  ( the files in the batch start with OPTTXM*)
exit /b 0

 if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0  goto error

echo Error!
sendmail.exe -t < error_mail.txt
move  ????????????????????????????????? ( how you can get inside each file and check the status
)
exit /b 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make WinSCP create [XML log](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml) with files that were and were not transferred.  But it would be difficult (if possible at all) to parse/process those XML files in a batch file.

You better use a more powerful scripting language, like PowerShell.
See for example [Move files after upload using PowerShell/WinSCP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48344586/850848).
(there are many other similar questions here)

There's also WinSCP article on this topic:
[Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please answer my new question i posted todat

Comment: I have asked you for a clarification already and you didn't answer yet.