# How WinSCP determined Errors?

Tags: winscp

Does WinSCP check the error level from the log file?
How WinSCP determined errors? what considers an error in WinSCP? There will have to be some testing with WinSCP.

for example 
 if you say something like “get eslam*”, the log will just say something like “no files match”.  But if you say “put eslam.txt” and it doesn’t exist, you will get the “Error code: 3”.  I don’t know if WinSCP will return an errorlevel for that.  It happens all the time and the BAT would think there was an error when it is an expected result.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: after i process my batch. i want to see if my files successful to move to folder success and send email through blat. if the batch fail they will in the same folder and send email through blat  with failure status.

Comment: i want to automate it. instead of looking at the log file. i want it to do it automatic, if the batch code 0 move files to folder name (folder) and send email saying success, if not leave it in same folder and log the error                                                                                                  for example every batch i have have over 1000 files how i can find out which files been send and which not ? is any way Winscp can tell me the state of the batch file by file ?

Comment: I have [already answered you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60423080/850848) that it is nearly impossible to enumerate *"which files been send and which not"* is a plain batch file. So why do you ask the same question again? Use WinSCP .NET assembly and PowerShell.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it .net assembly? im sorry if i repeated my self

Comment: I do not know what else to add. I wrote *"nearly impossible"*. So it is not the *only way*. But it would be way too difficult to do it in a batch file.